# Controlling the posterior probabilty threshold for LDA and QDA in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Consider the following use case (this is cribbed completely from An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, et al).

You're attempting to predict whether or not a credit card owner will default based on various personal data. You're using Linear Discriminant Analysis (or, for purpose of this question, Quadratic Discriminant Analysis).

You want your estimator to prioritize the true positive rate over the false positive rate. That is to say, correctly identifying an imminent default is more important than predicting a default that fails to materialize.

Is there a setting for this in the sklearn.lda.LDA and/or sklearn.qda.QDA classes? I thought perhaps building them with the class_prior named argument would be appropriate, but that doesn't appear to be accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the decision threshold by using the lda.predict_proba and then thresholding the probability manually:

```
lda = LDA().fit(X_train, y_train)
probs_positive_class = lda.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
# say default is the positive class and we want to make few false positives
prediction = probs_positive_class > .9
```

This will give you a very conservative estimate of whether they will default (it will only say they default if it is 90% certain).
Whether .9 actually corresponds to being 90% certain depends on how well [calibrated](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/calibration.html) the classifier is.

Comment: I'm glad to see a sklearn guru weighing in. Thanks so much. This solution strikes me as just as it should be. The API already has sufficient information for this kind of analysis, so no dedicated parameter is needed.